# How to use differentiation to show that a curve is symmetric above x axis

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, differential-algebra

If $x^2+y^2=9$, how can I show that this curve is symmetric above $x$-axis using differentiation.

Am I correct?

Clearly $\frac{dy}{dx} =-\frac{x}{y}$ . So for all $x$ in the domain, $y=+$ or $-$. So I have two same values with only a sign difference. Can I conclude by this reasoning that the curve is symmetric above $x$?

Or is there a good reasoning way to use differentiation to prove it.

Comment: When you talk about symmetry you must always specify what is the axis of symmetry? Here about which axis are looking for symmetry?

Comment: x axis or y axis . I need to know the proper way to do it

Comment: `is there a good reasoning way to use differentiation to prove it` Maybe you should dwell some more on why even consider/try to use differentiation to begin with. The given example has the obvious symmetries $\,f(x,y)=f(\pm x, \pm y)\,$, so it's not the best example to drive the point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the curves given by 
$$\begin{array} \\
x^2+y^2-9=0 & x\ge0  & y >0\\
x^2+(y-3)^2-9=0 & x\le0 & y>3
\end{array}$$

[Here is the plot.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vjaccbmgpe) So as you can see that the slope of tangents are equal at all values of $x=\pm a$. But they aren't symmetric.

So showing slopes are equal isn't a guarantee for symmetry. You must show that the values $f(a)=f(-a)$ to show symmetry.

[Here is another example.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5fm5sicwkw)